# Is there a synchronous function for jq?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, promise, jq

`jq.run('.', '/path/to/file.json').then(console.log)` is asynchronous so when I try to use it I get this: `Promise { <pending> }` AND THEN I get the result, but it's too late... so how can I fix this ?
I try to wait with `await` but I don't know where I can put this keyword. So here's my code:

```
const jq = require('node-jq')
const filter = '[.root[].A[].AT]'
const jsonPath = './simple.json'

 data = jq.run(filter, jsonPath).then((output) => {
    console.log(output)
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
  })

fs.appendFile('./jqTest.txt', data + "\r\n", function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("complete!")
});
```

Comment: You've already got a `.catch()`, just add a `.then()`.

Comment: so I add .then() AFTER the catch(....) ?

Comment: Well that's what you do with a Promise.

Comment: I add .then() AFTER catch and I get nothing it's the same result, so you ask me to do this right: `data = jq.run(filter, jsonPath).then((output) => {
    console.log(output)
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
  }).then()`
if this  what you asked me to do it doesn't work

Comment: I don't understand can you explain ?

Comment: Is there someone who can help me ? Because, litteraly no one on this planet has the same problem according to my internet researches....

Comment: The thing returns a Promise. To handle that, you add callbacks via `.then()`. The callback receives the value from the original operation as its argument. This is an extremely common, in fact pervasive, pattern in JavaScript programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of asynchronous APIs is that you can't write

```
data = getResultsAsynchronously();
doStuffWith(data);
...
```

(Unless you use `await`, which is slightly magical.)

Instead, traditional asynchronous APIs take a function to call when the result is ready:

```
getResultsAsynchronously(function (data) {
    doStuffWith(data);
    ...
});
```

I.e. all the code that follows the original function call in the synchronous version is instead put into a callback function and passed into `getResultsAsynchronously`.

Promises still follow this general pattern, but let you decouple starting the asynchronous operation itself from deciding how to handle the result. That is, you can start an asynchronous operation first and register a callback that handles the results later, in a second step:

```
promise = getResultsAsynchronously();
// and later:
promise.then(function (data) {
    doStuffWith(data);
    ...
});
```

However, you don't have to separate the two steps if you don't want to:

```
getResultsAsynchronously().then(function (data) {
    doStuffWith(data);
    ...
});
```

`.then` also returns a promise, to which you can attach further callbacks by calling `.then` or `.catch`.

In your code,

```
data = jq.run(filter, jsonPath).then(...).catch(...)
```

`data` is just another promise, but one without any useful return value inside (because your `then` and `catch` callbacks don't return any value).

To fix your logic, it should look like this:

```
jq.run(filter, jsonPath).then((data) => {
    fs.appendFile('./jqTest.txt', data + "\r\n", (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("complete!")
    });
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
});
```

To recap: Asynchronous results are only available inside callback functions. You can't use the return value like with a synchronous operation.

That said, `async` / `await` let you convert asynchronous code into synchronous code (or at least something that looks synchronous). However, this trick only works "on the inside": The external interface is still asynchronous, you can just write more normal looking code internally.

For example:

```
// await is only available inside async functions, so let's define one:
(async function () {

    // magic happens here:
    let data = await jq.run(filter, jsonPath);

    fs.appendFile('./jqTest.txt', data + "\r\n", (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("complete!")
    });

})();  // ... and invoke it immediately
```

Internally, JavaScript rewrites

```
x = await f();
doStuffWith(x);
...
```

into something that looks like

```
return f().then((x) => {
    doStuffWith(x);
    ...
});
```

i.e. `await` lets you pull the contents of a callback function out into straight line code. Ultimately the whole `async` function still returns a promise, however.